# Sending and fetching location data

Tags: android

I have an application whose current location is shown on the map.Now i want to send that location to the localhost server so for that i have done this.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "fffff", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {


        // String bp=lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),true);


        String bestprovider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestprovider);


        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double lng = l.getLongitude();


        Toast.makeText(this, "" + lat + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> Al = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
          //send to  server

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet htget = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/loc.php?lat="+la+"&lng="+lo);

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }








        String result;
        result = Al.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + Al.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + ", " + Al.get(0).getAddressLine(2) + ", " + Al.get(0).getAddressLine(3) + ", " + "lat=" + Al.get(0).getLatitude() + ", " + "lng=" + Al.get(0).getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).draggable(true).title("Current Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    } catch (Exception e) {


        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

I am using this php file for sending data to the database.I am testing this php in html and it gives me error that it can't be parsed.

```
<?php
$lat=$_GET['lat'];
$lng=$_GET['lng'];

$com=$_mysql("localhost","root","","images");
$sql="insert into MyLoc values('$lat','$lng');
$_mysql($com,$sql);
 <?php
```

This is not working. Please correct my code. and if possible also let me know how to fetch this data from another application.I am new to development.Just a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what does not work? And what does work? Any errors? Any exceptions? Does the 'fffff' toast display? What else? Which other toasts?

Comment: You are really testing this on an emulator?

Comment: yes i tested it on emulator and it's not working. Also i tried inserting data in database through html file and this php and it was not working. I guess there is error in this php file.

Comment: Yes ffff toast is being displayed.

Comment: If you want help you should tell much more. Start with answering all my questions. I wonder why you did not answer them.

Comment: Actually this code runs current location is shown but i want to send the current location to the server and that is not happening. My current location is not posted into databse and also no error comes. When i tried running this php through html page the error shows which is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end". I think my java code is correct but there is problem with php code.

Comment: I asked you to tell which toasts you see. So mention them please. And if the toast with resp comes then you should tell whats in it.

Comment: First toast is being displayed. the location toast is also displayed. and the toasts i have for catch block where i am trying to send data to localhost is not being displayed. No error is showing still the data is not being written to database.

Comment: And the toast with resp? Didnt i ask that too?

Comment: The data is not being written to the database? Which data? Do you know if data is coming in to begin with? Start with checking if the right data is coming in and let your php script echo the data and comments. Then add android code to read the echos from the input stream.

Comment: Replace the second `<?php` by `?>`.

Comment: The current location is shown on the map. the latitude and longitude is displayed.Now i want to send that data to the database. So,yes the right data is coming. first ffff is getting printed.Then the current latitude and longitude is getting printed. Nothing is displayed after that.

Comment: `So,yes the right data is coming. ` ???? I asked if the data was coming in the php script.

Comment: .`Then the current latitude and longitude is getting printed`. Why are you saying `getting printed` ? You have a toast there. Does that toast display? Why dont you report in a normal manner? Does the first toast with ffff really display or do you have a log statement that prints?

Comment: the toast with ffff is being displayed and then the current latitude and longitude is being displayed.

Comment: Can you please send me complete code for sending current latitude and longitude to the server and please also send the php script.

Comment: Now find out which statement is the last that gets executed. You have no exception? Look in the LogCar.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Clearly displayed in the LogCat of your IDE. Look for it first as it could have saved you and us a lot of time if you had mentioned that right away.  You have to place the http network code in an AsyncTask or thread.